# Derivative with summation operator

Tags: derivatives

How do you take the derivative when there is a summation operator in this step..

$$\frac{d}{dt} \left[1-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!} \right] = 
\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \left(\sum_0^{k-1}\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} - \lambda \sum_{n=0}^{k-2} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\right)$$

Comment: It is a finite sum, just differentiate each term and sum up!

Comment: I don't understand how it got split up into two summation terms..

Comment: You're missing some parentheses there.  Anyway, the key here is the product rule.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} f_n(t) = 
\frac{d}{dt} (f_0(t) + \cdots + f_{k-1}(t)) = 
\frac{df_0}{dt} + \cdots + \frac{df_{k-1}}{dt}
=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{df_n}{dt}
$$
Also, note (after going through the product rule) that
$$
\sum(f_n(t) + g_n(t)) = \sum f_n(t) + \sum g_n(t)
$$